# event driven methods and execution sequence in c#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, events, methods

Hypothetically speaking, if I had two methods (event handlers) driven by the same event, which method is executed first?

Example:

```
obj.SomeEvent += new SomeEventHandler(method1);
obj.SomeEvent += new SomeEventHandler(method2);
```

Which is called first?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It's up to the event publisher, but *usually* it would be whichever handler was added to the event first. That's the default implementation for an event which is basically implemented using a delegate. So for example:

```
SomeDelegate eventHandlers = null;
eventHandlers += FirstHandler;
eventHandlers += SecondHandler;
eventHandlers(...);
```

That will *definitely* call `FirstHandler` before `SecondHandler`. However, there's no guarantee that an event *will* be implemented just using delegates like that.

EDIT: While the event handling behaviour is up to the event publisher, the delegate combination part is well-specified in the C# language specification, section 7.8.4:

> [...] Otherwise, the result of the operation is a new delegate instance that, when invoked, invokes the first operand and then invokes the second operand.

The BCL [`Delegate.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30cyx32c.aspx) method makes a similar guarantee (emphasis mine):

> (Return value) A new delegate with an invocation list that concatenates the invocation lists of a and b **in that order**. Returns a if b is null, returns b if a is a null reference, and returns a null reference if both a and b are null references.

Comment: Out of interest, is there some evidence or something to cite for this?

Comment: @KierenJohnstone: Which part - how delegates are implemented? The C# language specification guarantees the result of combining using `+` in section 7.8.4.

Comment: Yup exactly.  Aha I found that part you mean: "Otherwise, the result of the operation is a new delegate instance that, when invoked, invokes the first operand and then invokes the second operand."

Answer (score 1):

The first subscribed one. "First in - first served".

Answer (score 1):

The default implementation will cause event handlers to be called in the order they were added, however, it is possible to customize this behaviour. If the behaviour is customized, the client cannot tell this. So the real answer to your question is that the order in which event handlers is raised "depends" and could even change at runtime, however, the vast majority of events have default implementation.

For example:

```
public class ReverseBling
{
    private readonly List<EventHandler> _blings = new List<EventHandler>();

    public event EventHandler Bling
    {
        add
        {
            _blings.Add(value);
        }
        remove
        {
            _blings.Remove(value);
        }
    }

    public void RaiseBling()
    {
        for (int i = _blings.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            _blings[i](this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}

private static void Main()
{
    ReverseBling bling = new ReverseBling();
    bling.Bling += delegate { Console.WriteLine(0);};
    bling.Bling += delegate { Console.WriteLine(1); };
    bling.Bling += delegate { Console.WriteLine(2); };
    bling.RaiseBling();
}
```

Output:

> 2
>    1
>    0

Comment: Note that even without the custom "raise" behaviour, this will already behave differently to "normal" events - as normally the "remove" would remove the *last* occurrence of the given delegate, not the *first*.

Comment: @Jon Agreed, just a quick example of what's possible.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way of telling which event handler will be invoked first.  Many people think the first one to subscribe will be invoked first (which is normally the case) but not specified by the CLI.

Comment: It's not totally random - it depends on how the event is implemented, and that can be easily documented, and is *not* up to the CLR. For example, if it's implemented just using a delegate then that's *guaranteed* to preserve "combination order", i.e. `Delegate.Combine(x, y)` will return a delegate which, when invoked, will invoke the invocation list within `x` and then the invocation list within `y`.

Comment: I'm sure in a C# book I've read that when subscribing to event handlers you can't guarantee the order they get called.  Obviously if you're the one controlling the invoking you can but what if you subscribe to delegates to the mouse click event, I'm sure they could get called in either order.

Comment: Check out this MVP article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb508935.aspx in particular this sentence: "Generally, delegates are called in the order they were added but this behavior is not specified within the CLI specification and furthermore, it can be overridden. Therefore, programmers should not depend on an invocation order"

Comment: Actually, for just delegates, it *is* guaranteed. It's not part of the CLI specification - it's part of both the BCL specification and the C# specification. Now events are slightly different, and it *is* up to the event publisher - but that's not the same as saying it's "totally random" as per your original answer. It's generally *not specified* by event publishers, but it certainly can be - and events implemented using field-like events in C# will have the "natural" sequential behaviour.